# Op amp based DC-DC voltage doubler

Tags: operational-amplifier, dc, dc-dc-converter, voltage-doubler

I have a `LM471` op-amp and a single DC 5V source. Is it possible to double the source voltage using this op-amp? Can the op-amp be powered by the very signal to be amplified? I tried simulating such situation in Multisim and it seems power/signal have to be from different sources. Why is that?

A segment on my 7 segment display requires voltage higher than 5V. I want to boost my 5V power (double it, for example) and use the boosted voltage to lit the display. I don't want to use a separate power source just to power the op-amp. I understand the out current will be lower, but it doesn't matter in my situation.

Of course different elements might be necessary in this circuit, but I don't want to use things like 555 timers, just analog parts.

Comment: POWER out MUST be less than POWER in. There are ways to produce voltages > Vin and > Vsupply - usually using more than 1 opamp or an opamp + other parts BUT you need to say what you really are trying to do as your question could mean several things.

Comment: I'll assume that's a lm741.  Not the best opamp to power from only 5V.  So I think you are asking for a circuit that will somehow bootstrap 5V into a higher voltage.. that then power's that same circuit to a higher voltage.  That's kinda fun...but I think you'll need at least one more pass element.  You've got to feed more power to the power supply than just goes through the opamp.

Comment: What exactly is an "LM471"? [This?](http://www.backtonormandy.org/the-history/air-force-operations/airplanes-allies-and-axis-lost/lancaster/LM4711944-03-25.html)

Comment: [How to unscrewing large bolts with swiss army knife?](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/3383/7036)  This question (in its original version) fits that profile.

Comment: @NickAlexeev That would be an odd car (not impossible, just really odd) that required unscrewing [bolts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lug_nut#Design) rather than (lug) nuts to change a tire.

Comment: 555 timer is as much an analog part as an opamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a microcontroller (as I suspect) driving your display, you could probably use a spare pin with pwm to drive a simple capacitive voltage doubler. Thus you'd need only common parts (caps, diode, a bjt/mosfet) - no need for 555, opamp or whatever and no inductor so little added noise.

Edit : here is the classic voltage doubler circuit :

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fz2dVz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

C1 should be much smaller than C2 (lower C1 gives lower ripple, but lower curtent capacity and slower voltage ramp-up), and critically diodes should have lowest possible Vf. You won't get exactly doubling from this circuit as it is, but for what I guess your application is that may not matter much.

Drive PWM pin by setting it to 127, and choose frequency matching C1 (or C1 matching the PWM frequency).

Comment: Can you post a link to a sample circuit of such doubler?

Comment: I added a schematic of the classic voltage doubler. Plenty to be found on the net (google "capacitive voltage multiplier" or "charge pump")

Comment: You need to be careful about exceeding the current specs on whatever you're using to drive this, obviously

Comment: True; the current at input is at least 2 times the current at output. Also if you try to pull much current from a mcu pin, the voltage at that pin will decrease. So obviously this won't provide 50mA at 10V. However if you only need 1 or 2mA, if 8V and some ripple is fine, then this approach may be the simplest (lowest component count, only common parts)

Comment: The circuit in this answer is wrong - it will produce approximately 4V dc and misses the point. D1 should not connect to ground it should connect to +5V.

Comment: @Andyaka Ooops, that's very true... I edited the schematic in the answer.